# Proving the sum and product full for null sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to show that if we suppose $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $b_{n} \rightarrow 0$ and we have $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ that ($ca_{n} + db_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ and $(a_{n}b_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ and that these two results generalise for $k$ null sequences.

Attempt (sum rule):

Since $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, |a_{n}| < \epsilon, n > N$. Similarly for $b_{n}$. Consider $|ca_{n} + db_{n}|$ then we have the following:

$$ 0 \leq |ca_{n} + db_{n}| \leq (|c| + |d|)\epsilon$$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have a null sequence.

Question about sum rule proof:

1. Can I just assume that $ca_{n}$ and $db_{n}$ produces a null sequence or do I need to prove that before using the result? Clearly if $c, d=0$ it is trivial. If they don't equal $0$ then it requires a little bit more work.
2. To formally show this holds for $k$ null-sequences, would this be an induction type proof? It is clear that you can just extend the argument, but I'm not sure how to present it formally.

Attempt at product rule roof:

Suppose $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, |a_{n}| < \epsilon, n > N$. Similarly for $b_{n}$.

Since $|a_{n}| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |a_{n}| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Similarly for $b_{n}$. Now consider |a_{n}b_{n}| \leq |a_{n}||b_{n}| \leq epsilon$. Hence it is a null sequence.

Questions about the product rule proof:

1. To extend this to $k$ null-sequences is it just a case of, for each null-sequence take the k-th root of $\epsilon$ then when we multiply all $k$ null-sequences together, we have the product is less than $\epsilon$. However I'm not too sure how to formally present that?

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, to simplify for the sum we can take $\forall \varepsilon>0$

$$|a_n|< \frac \varepsilon {2|c|}, \quad |b_n|< \frac \varepsilon {2|d|}$$

then

$$|ca_n+db_n|\le|ca_n|+|db_n|=|c||a_n|+|d||b_n| < \varepsilon$$

For the product, $\forall \varepsilon>0$

$$|a_n|<\sqrt\varepsilon, \quad |b_n|<\sqrt\varepsilon$$

then

$$|a_nb_n|=|a_n||b_n| < \varepsilon$$

Comment: thanks that makes sense. To generalise it for $k$ null sequences I guess we just use the exact same argument but as a sum / product of $k$ terms...

Comment: @Mathlearner Yes of course it can be generalized by means of the same argument.